# jquery validate empty field

Tags: jquery, validation

I have a question related to jquery. Basically I want to do a very simple thing. I have a text input field. On submit, I want to display error message if the field is empty.
I have done this way:

```
 errMsg = "Please write name";              
    $("div#errMsg").css("background-color", "red");
     $("div#errMsg").html(errMsg);
```

and in the HTML:

```
<div id="errMsg"></div>
    <strong>Name:  </strong>
    <input name="name" id="name" type="text" maxlength="255" size="50" />
```

It works fine, however there is a problem. When I leave the field empty and it displays the error message, the error message does not go away without refreshing the page.
I am trying to do it so that when there is error message, and i type something in the field, it automatically remove the error without refreshing the page.
Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#name').keyup(function() {

   if ($(this).val()) {
       $("div#errMsg").fadeOut(100);
   }

});
```

Be sure to call `show()` `$("div#errMsg")` next time you display it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Im trying to do the same way, however i still cant make it work as Im very new to jquery. can you please give some example to use it? eg. like you said, how can i show() next time?

Comment: @user523364 Change the line from the example you gave to `$("div#errMsg").css("background-color", "red").show();`

Answer (score 0):

Register a listener for the [keypress event](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/). Then you can re-validate the field every time the user types something in it. An alternative is to use the [change event](http://api.jquery.com/change/), which is only triggered when the user changes the field, and then switches the focus to something else.